# How to pass data between three different servers in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC with C# .There is a requirement in one of my project to pass data between three servers.

Below is detailed explanation of scenario:

1) There is Server 1 (Webserver) where website has been hosted through IIS.

2) Server1 send request to Server2

3) Server2 send response to Server3.
  (Server2 can't send response directly to server1)

4) Server3 pass response back to Server1.

How to handle case when there is connection break between server3 and server1 ?As in any case server1 redirection from server3 is mandatory to know current status.

More details:
This project is related with shopping cart.
Server1 is where website is hosted on IIS,customer select products and start payment process.Server2 is payment gateway(But as per client requirement payment gateway will not send response back to website i.e. server1, It will send response to another server i.e. server3).Server3 is redundant server and is connected with web server.It is hosted on IIS and used for getting response from payment gateway and pass it to Webserver. So Server3 acts as a interface  between server 1 and server2.

Please guide me for best possible solution?

Comment: Is this for handling API requests in a chain - or are you talking about the actual web request? I am not sure you would want to be in a situation where you are passing the request between servers. I think there is a better architecture - Perhaps services behind a load balancers?

Comment: Can you please tell us what type of apps hosted in Server2/Server3? IIS or windows service or other?

Comment: On the first request from server1 mark the status of request as `pending`, then when the response comes from server3 your can update the status to `complete`. so in any case that connection break or error you will have records of pending and completed requests

Comment: What you're talking about isn't technically feasible. HTTP implements a request-response model. If Server1 sends a request to Server2, Server2 needs to send a response back to Server1 *at some point*. In creating that response, Server2, itself, can communicate with other servers, i.e. Server3, but the response to Server1 must come from Server2. Server3 cannot send a response to Server1, because Server1 did not initiate a request to Server3.

Comment: @Mehmood will that help if this is some synchronous request process? if using the statuses as you have described he would then need to also handle retry requests and other code to support this? I think we need more info on what is happening first

Comment: @MichaelLake Obviously. It was just a rough idea, then he can do as per their project.

Comment: First of all Thanks for all comments.I modified question in more details.

@Mehmood : I done communcation between servers in same way as you suggested in one of my previous project when server2 send response back to server1 .Will also implement same in current project also.
          
@MichaelLake/@Chris Pratt/@Raj Nagalingam : Please have a look on edited question.

Answer (score 1):

If you a loosely coupled communication style and also asyncronous then go for Queue and use Publish/Subscribe pattern.

Lets say you have a Queue named MessageingQueue and inside this queue there are 3 Topics

First one is Server1ToServer2
Second one is Server2ToServer3
Third one is Server3ToServer1

Server 1 will subscribe for messages on Server3ToServer1
Server 2 will subscribe for messages on Server1ToServer2
Server 3 will subscribe for messages on Server2ToServer3

Server 1 will send a message to Server1ToServer2 queue, Server 2 will pick it up and send a message to Server2ToServer3 topic which will be picked by server 3, and lastly server 3 will send the last response to Server3ToServer1